# Stop fluid inflow without droplets

Tags: keyframes, fluid-simulation

Apologies to bother with this question seeing there were a few suggestions the site tried to give but all of them seemed years old and don't seem to be working.

On blender 2.8, I've been trying to make a simple animation of water filling a cup, and when near the top the water would stop. Yet when adding keyframes of when flow is on, then off, the steady stream turns to droplets and barely fills. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: it is possible that your domain is to small and the fluid is getting to the top or close to it and that is stopping the fluid from flowing anymore

Comment: Sorry if explained wrong, I meant like I want the inflow to be a steady stream filling the cup but it seems to only do that if I let it run all 250 frames(And then the cup overfills and into the domain space. If I try to stop the animation early at like 100 frames out of 250 the steady stream turns to droplets and barely fills the cup